# How to get three element after an particular index of a array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have two array

```
const array1 = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
const array2 = [17, 18]
```

I want to return first three element from array1 after comparing the index of array2 **17** element or first element with the array1.

**desired O/P from array1 after comparing is [14, 15, 16]**

i have tried getting the index of the particular element.

```
const indexOf17FromArray1 = array1.indexOf(array2[0]) //5
```

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Elaborate.

Comment: what is `18` in `array2` doing?

Comment: I think he wants to pass in a slice and get back the 3 elements before the slice .

Comment: @NinaScholz 18 is just another element in the array.

Comment: @NicolaiChristensen i just want to return the first three element after a particular index in array1 and index is dynamic

Comment: You say *after* but your example is before.. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

just do array.slice((idx - 3), idx)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the use of array methods [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

First determine the last index (like you already have). Then based on your desired length modify it for use with `slice`. `slice` takes the start and end indices.

```js
const array1 = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
const array2 = [17, 18];

const length = 3;

const indexOf17FromArray1 = array1.indexOf(array2[0])
console.log(array1.slice(indexOf17FromArray1 - length,  indexOf17FromArray1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the index and check if `-1` or subtract an offset and get a new array.

```js
const
    array = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
    value = 17,
    index = array.indexOf(value),
    result = index === -1
        ? []
        : array.slice(Math.max(index - 3, 0), index);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of the element you want as reference.

```
const index = array1.indexOf(array2[0]);
```

If you want 3 elements after this index:

```
array1.slice(index + 1, index + 4);
```

If you want 3 elements before this index:

```
array1.slice(index - 3, index);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Finding the index of element = 17 in array1:**

```
const array1 = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
const array2 = [17, 18];

const position17 = array1.findIndex(e => e === array2[0]);
```

The method findIndex will loop through array1 and check if the current element(e) is equal to array2[0].

**Creating an array only with the three elements prior to element 17:**

Here you will use the filter method, I'm passing the current value(item) and it's index. This method will check if the index is below "positon17" and if it is whitin the first three elements prior to element 17.

```
const newArray = array1.filter((item, index)=> (index < position17 & index >=position17-3)&& item);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple function that will give you the next three after

your supplied index.

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const index = 2;
const threeElementsAfterIndex = [];
for( let i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    if(i > index && i < index + 3) {
        threeElementsAfterIndex.push(array[i]);
    }
}
return threeElementsAfterIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const index = 2;


console.log(array.slice(index + 1, index + 4));
```